# Java: How to add or create a new object with arguments and add it to a queue?

Tags: java, constructor, queue

I am writing a program for which students going to the cashier of particular department or faculty are given a token number which is automatically generated and they line up in a queue to wait for their turn to enter. The program should allow the user to insert a new student in the queue by adding his name and token number into the system among its other features.

I don't know how to add a new student to the queue.

Here is what I have come up so far:

**Student class**

```
package queues;

import java.util.Random;

public class Student {

    private String name;

    private int  tnum;

public Student(String name, int tnum){
    this.name=name;
    this.tnum=tnum;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public int getTnum() {
    return tnum;
}


public void setTnum(int tnum) {
    this.tnum = tnum;
}


public String toString(){
    return "Student name: "+ name+ "  Token num: "+tnum;
    }

}
```

---

**Main class**

```
package queues;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student_Main{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    int opt;

    Student stdt= new Student("Sophia", 1);
    Student stdt2= new Student("Amelia", 2);
    Student stdt3= new Student("Karxlina", 4);
    Student stdt4= new Student("Rachel", 3);

    Queue<Student> stdtQ= new LinkedList<Student>();

    stdtQ.add(stdt);
    stdtQ.add(stdt2);
    stdtQ.add(stdt3);
    stdtQ.add(stdt4);

    System.out.println(stdtQ);

    System.out.println("Please choose an option. ");
    System.out.println("To insert new student, enter 1.");

    opt= sc.nextInt();

    if(opt==1){
        stdtQ.add(Student(sc.hasNext(), sc.nextInt())); /*this doesn't work of course*/
      }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
stdtQ.add(new Student(sc.hasNext(), sc.nextInt()));
```

Comment: Thanks! It should be `stdtQ.add(new Student(sc.next(), sc.nextInt()));` though

Answer (score 1):

Queues typically order elements in a FIFO manner. So if you are interested in using the token number to sort the queue you should check priority queues.

By calling the `add` method you are already adding new elements to the `stdtQ` queue. If you want toadd other students to that queue you fist have to create the object ( by getting the values from the input for example) and the add it with the `add` method.

You can print all the student in the queue like this:

```
for(Student s : stdtQ){
    System.out.println(s.getName() + s.getTnum());
}
```